# Write to EBX register eventually leads to program segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, x86, g++, cpu, inline-assembly

I have a curious case of the ebx register causing a segfault when I perform any writing operation on it. I can't figure out why. Is there some limitation of the ebx register where I can't use it? I have tried using other registers with this algorithm and it functions. It's only when I use the ebx register than I get a segmentation fault. 
I'm using x86-32 architecture, Intel syntax with the GCC style of inline assembly code.

```
//code (c)opyright Daniel (Robin) Smith
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    int s, i;
    [redacted]

    asm (
            "\n"

           [redacted]

            "       call    series\n"
            "       jmp     finished\n"

            "series:\n"
            "       push    ebp\n"
            "       mov     ebp,esp\n"

            "       mov     ebx,0x1\n"

            [redacted]

            "series_exit:\n"
            "       leave\n"
            "       ret\n"

            "finished:"
            :"=a"(s)
            :"a"(i)
    );
    [redacted]
}
```

Comment: Your code is full of undefined behaviour.  You are not allowed to clobber arbitrary registers in gcc-style inline assembly without telling the compiler.  You probably get a crash because `ebx` is a callee-saved register, but it's hard to tell.  Before continuing your attempts, kindly [read the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

Comment: You alter registers EBX, ECX, EDX without letting the compiler know. You'll at least need to add them to the clobbers list. `:"=a"(series)
            :"a"(input) : "ebx", "ecx", "edx")`.I'd also recommend placing `%=` on the end of each of your labels.

Comment: I did indeed RT(F)M. I forgot I needed to add the registers to the clobber list. Thanks!

Comment: Title is misleading. The segmentation fault is not at the point you write to ebx, but rather some time afterward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not use any registers in gcc inline assembly without letting the compiler know. The reason that you see a problem using ebx is that ebx is the compiler's first choice for a register to put a value that it needs to keep around for a while. However, your use of ecx and edx is also incorrect.

For information on the use of inline assembly, and how to designate registers for inputs, outputs, and clobbers, see the links at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info. (Information on clobbers is at http://ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.3.)

In particular, see https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm. The code you have written would be better written as regular out-of-line assembly function in a .s file, rather than as inline assembly. Of course, then you would have to learn about calling conventions.

Comment: It's not a “should not,” it's a “must not.”

Comment: I'd also venture to guess the segfault here with EBX is related to position independent code as it would usually point to the GOT. Of course you could get any type of undefined behavior but with PIC code modifying EBX is often fatal.